# next-i18next: Fetch data from HTTP api call and apply to resource

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I'm trying to do i18n translation using [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) in Next.js

My current code in
**_app.ts**

```js
export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await api.get('/translation');
  const name = res.data.name as string;

  return {
    props: await serverSideTranslations(name, [name], {
      i18n: {
        defaultLocale: name,
        locales: [name],
      },
      lng: name,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
      },
      resources: {
        [res.data.name]: {
          translation: res.data.config,
        },
      },
    }),
  };
};
```

I'm getting an api response with a translation json in it. The current one is not applying translations to page

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/next

Comment: Hello @Swapnil, did you end up using `i18next-http-backend` or how have you handle the translation content from API?

Comment: @TommyLeong yes I've been using the public folder for that

Comment: @SwapnilSoni when you say you've been using public folder, meaning your translation content is always part of the build. You're not reading it from API, am I correct?

Comment: @TommyLeong Correct